# User Interface - Dropdown

Tags: user-interface

What is the best way to design an interface so that very long drop down values that get trucated due to size limits do not create a very bad user experience. My question is for web applications.

Could you please send your suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean very long values, or a very long list of values?

Comment: hehe... I could not understand the same thing... so, answered for both! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what I have done in such a case is:

1. Using autocomplete (so that the user can start typing and get at the intended option faster).
2. Have the dropdown of a fixed length like 30 chars. Now, if the value of the drop down is longer I just truncate it to 25 with a '...' at the end. A hover on this value will make the full text appear as a 'title' or similar.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use 'type-ahead' with postback (AJAX) to reduce the size of the list.

Comment: Can you explain further what this is?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a another window (div?) with list/grid with paging instead of dropdown.
Its very intuitive for general users.

Comment: I think using another window is a horrible user experience for users. I personally wouldn't do it that way.

Comment: What is a "general user"? I ge the impression that neither Mitch nor me belong to that group.

Answer (score 0):

have a tooltip for each item in the dropdown list so when a user hovers his mouse pointer to an item, he'll still be able to see the full description of the item.

or have your dropdown width auto-resize to the longest description in the list.